# Odoo 11 add popup SyntaxError:

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I have a module that works in Odoo 10. I migrated the code to odoo 11 but still having issues.

Here is my JS file

```
odoo.define('pos_custom.pos_global_discount', function(require) {
    "use strict";

    var models = require('point_of_sale.models');
    var screens = require('point_of_sale.screens');
    var gui = require('point_of_sale.gui');
    var PopupWidget = require('point_of_sale.popups');
    var utils = require('web.utils');
    var round_pr = utils.round_precision;
    var _super_order = models.Order.prototype;
    models.Order = models.Order.extend({
        initialize: function(attributes,options){
            _super_order.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

     screens.ProductScreenWidget.include({
        click_product: function(product) {
            if (this.pos.config.custom_discount_product_id &&
                this.pos.config.custom_discount_product_id[0] == product.id) {
                this.pos.gui.show_popup('add_discount_product_popup', {
                    product: product,
                    product_options: {}
                });
            } else {
                this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        },
    });




    var AddDiscountProductPopup = PopupWidget.extend({
        template: 'AddDiscountProductPopup',
        show: function(options){
            options = options || {}
            this.product = options.product
            this.product_options = options.product_options
            this._super(options);
            this.$('.discount_product').focus();
            this.$('.discount_product').on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {
               //this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
                $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
                if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
                (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        },


        click_confirm: function(){
            var order = this.pos.get_order();
            var $value = this.$('.discount_product').val();
            $value = $.isNumeric($value) ? parseFloat($value) : 0.00;
            this.product_options['price'] = -$value;
            this.product_options['hide_popup'] = true;
            order.add_product(this.product, this.product_options);
            this.gui.close_popup();
        },
    });
    gui.define_popup({name:'add_discount_product_popup', widget: AddDiscountProductPopup});
});
```

I am getting SyntaxError: missing } after property list. note: { opened at line 1701, column 388

I think it is something to do with below but I am only guessing.
..

```
models.Order = models.Order.extend({
        initialize: function(attributes,options){
            _super_order.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the comma after the right curly brace. The comma is to indicate there's something else in the series and there's two places where you have it even though it's the end of the series.

Change `},` to `}`

Answer (score 0):

Replace That 3 lines with below code.

```
models.Order = models.Order.extend({
            initialize: function(attributes,options){
                _super_order.initialize.apply(this, arguments);


                 after this lines put below brackets.

               },
    });
```